# Moving an ImageView on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I'm trying to write an app to play Snakes and Ladders (this is the first app I've ever written, and i'm just doing it for fun...not for a course or commercial purposes or anything).

So my problem is, I want to move my ImageView of a player token from one square on the board to another square. I don't know how to do two things:

1. How can I place the imageview of the token on top of the board imageview in the layout?
2. How can I go about moving the token imageview itself by a certain % of the size of the board imageview? Is this possible or am I supposed to do this some other way?

I have classes written for the player, board and squares that all work fine. I just need to know what to do with the player's token. (I have tested it by displaying a toast message saying the player location every time I roll the die).

Here is the xml code for the layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:background="@drawable/stripes_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toGameListButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:background="@drawable/alternate_button_background"
            android:text="Quit"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/restartButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:background="@drawable/alternate_button_background"
            android:text="Restart"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTurn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="TextView set to Player&apos;s turn"
        android:textColor="#FF9900"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.7" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/game_board"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Board"
            android:src="@drawable/snakes_and_ladders_raw_board" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/green_indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rollButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@drawable/alternate_button_background"
        android:text="Roll!"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Let me know if I'm supposed to be more specific in my problem or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I place the imageview of the token on top of the board
>   imageview in the layout?

You can simply put both ImageViews into a RelativeLayout and then make sure that the ImageView of the token is below (in code) the ImageView of the board.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/game_board"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Board"
            android:src="@drawable/snakes_and_ladders_raw_board" />

        <!-- views below in code will be on top -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/green_indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> How can I go about moving the token imageview itself by a certain % of
>   the size of the board imageview? Is this possible or am I supposed to
>   do this some other way?

You could access the board ImageView width property and animate the token ImageView accordingly.

```
ImageView board = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.board);
ImageView token = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.token);

// animates the token imageview to the right side by 50% of the boardimageviews width
token.animate().x(board.getWidth() / 2).setDuration(500);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Okay, I didn't realize relativelayouts allowed that. And i'll try out the whole animate() thing now.

Comment: Be aware that the animate() method on views only works in API >= 12. For lower API levels, take a look at TranslateAnimation.

Comment: Okay, yeah i'll look into TranslateAnimation instead since I want to try to support below API 12 too. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Did you manage to get your code to work concerning the token being on top? Dont forget to select the correct answer if it works.